# Disable refresh icon on Menu while content is being refreshed

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a refresh icon on my menu which when clicked will refresh the contents of the Activity. But the problem is that the refresh icon is still clickable while it is refreshing which I do not want. Here is my menu.xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_refresh"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

And here is where I handle the click event for the icon

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        // getData() fetches the data and updates the display
        getData();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Also, is there a way to maybe dim the icon so that the user knows that they have already clicked the icon?

Comment: Do you have some callback when the refresh is done? Maybe you can disable it temporarily, and enable it once the refresh is done?

Comment: Inside the getData() method, after I fetch the data, I update the display. Is that what a callback is? I'm sorry. I'm very new to Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the icon, use the `isEnabled()` method of your Menuitem to check if it is currently enabled. If it is, then disable it until the data is loaded. Once the data loads successfully, then you can enable it again. Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(item.isEnabled()) {
            // "Dim" the icon like you said. You can use other alpha values if you like.
            item.getIcon().setAlpha(130);
            // Disable the menu icon
            item.setEnabled(false);

        }
        getData();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Now, you said that you have a `getData()` method which updates the display after it fetches the data. Once the data is fetched, check if the `Menuitem` is disabled. If it is disabled, then enable it again. Example:

```
if(item != null && item.isEnabled() == false) {
        // "Undim" the icon
        item.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
        // Enable it again
        item.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setEnabled(true) method to enable/disable menu item

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second `menu.xml`, that is used after the refresh button is clicked. To force a menu redraw call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

In this second `menu.xml`, the refresh button could be disabled, or switched to a diffrent one, indicating the user, that the refresh is on going.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to fix this is to hold on to the menu item in your activity.

```
private MenuItem mRefreshItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater infl = new MenuInflater(this);
    infl.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    mRefreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/** Call this when you begin or end loading */
private void setRefreshEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mRefreshItem.setEnabled(enabled);
}
```